# Can someone explain how this code is compiling

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I'm 110% brand new to coding and I'm learning Java. I have been following along with Codecademy with their Java course and it's been great so far, but I don't know how some of this program works:

```
public class Store {
    //instance fields
    String productType;

    //constructor method
    public Store(String product) {
        productType = product;
    }

    public void greetCustomer(String customer) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the store, " + customer + "!");
    }

    //advertise method
    public void advertise() {
        String message = "Selling " + productType + "!";
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Store lemonadeStand = new Store("Lemonade");
        lemonadeStand.greetCustomer("Tyler");
    }
}
```

The output of this is: "Welcome to the store, Tyler!"

But what is happening with the rest of the code? Does an output only happen when its method is called in main()? Did I only call the advertise() method and the others are left out of the output?

Thanks for the help! I'm really trying to get in to the habit of learning what my code actually does instead of just making something that works and not knowing why!

Comment: You are not calling the `advertise` method, so the `Selling ...` message is not printed. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: you need to call advertise too. lemonadeStand.advertise();

Comment: Have a look at [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).  It'll be a much faster and more effective way to learn Java than asking questions on StackOverflow each time you come across some little thing or another that you don't understand.

Comment: Whoops, looks like i mistyped what I meant to ask, rookie mistake! But I got the answer I was looking for and more. I'll be checking out the Java Tutorials for more info on stuff. Thanks again for the clarification everyone

Comment: Honestly its more that I'm really new and frankly not that great at Java so I dont understand it very well. The basics themselves are a bit difficult to grasp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any Java program, main() method is the entry point. You compile your code to class file. Then you execute the class file to run the program. At run time, JRE will check for main() method in the class file. It will start executing code from there. If there is no main() method, JRE will throw error. So to execute any piece of code, you should make sure that you are calling it from main() method or calling it from a method which is actually getting called from the main method. In this case, you can call advertise() from main method or call it from greetCustomer() method which is getting called from main() method. In both cases, you will get the expected line printed in the console.

Comment: This was a wonderful explanation! I was in the right direction for understanding that concept but wanted to make sure I was actually understanding what I needed to know. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions, the rest of your code is just present and yes you need to have your methods called in main() to run the code. And like Sweeper said, you did not call advertise method, only GreetCustomer().

If I were to look at your code, this is actually how I'd see it step-by-step:

First you create a String variable called productType.

Then in your first method public Store() you are taking in an argument(the input in the bracket) and assigning productType to be that value.

You then have a greetCustomer() method that takes in a String argument called 'customer' and the method prints "Welcome to the store '(parameter value called customer)'!".

Your advertise() method does not take in an input but rather prints the message line.

Main creates a new Store variable called lemonadeStand and the productType variable/string is set to "Lemonade"

What you are printing is the greetCustomer() method which is called in main as lemonadeStand.greetCustomer("Tyler") which takes in "Tyler" as the arg and returns "Welcome to the store Tyler!"

If you wanted to get advertise you'd do lemonadeStand.advertise();

Comment: Ahhh yes I see that now. I meant to say greetCustomer(). Thanks for the clarification!